# Fluent-card support for absolute positioned flyouts

Tags: fluent-ui

In a fluent card, if I place a select element with a dropdown and the height of the dropdown menu is larger than the card, it will extend past the card.

[image: card]

If I have an absolute positioned flyout, however, the content is still fixed to the card and is largely inaccessible.

Is there a way to mimic the behavior of the select dropdown for flyouts?

See this sample, ideally the absolute positioned popup will behave similar to the volvo select:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mgt-ts-next-starter-9exxfa?file=index.html

Comment: I wish i could give out to you a lot of points...the CSS property 
   content-visibility: visible;
is what I was looking for to solve my own issue of dropdown hiding behind Flient-Card container